# Python Global Variable Import

Tags: python

Let's say I have a `config.py` file that stores a global variable that will be used in multiple modules (in the same package):

```
# pkg/config.py
GLOBAL_VAL = 4
```

```
# pkg/module_A.py
from . import config

def func_A(x):
    return config.GLOBAL_VAL * x
```

```
# pkg/module_B.py
from . import config

def func_B(x):
    return config.GLOBAL_VAL + x
```

And then, I have a `main.py` that might call these functions:

```
# main.py

from pkg import module_A, module_B

x = 5
module_A.func_A(x)
module_B.func_B(x)

# Prints:
# 20
# 9
```

This is fine. However, there are times when a user may want to change `GLOBAL_VAL` and it seems like the natural thing to do is to import it and then set the value:

```
# main.py

from pkg import module_A, module_B
from pkg.config import GLOBAL_VAL

GLOBAL_VAL = 100
x = 5
print(module_A.func_A(x))
print(module_B.func_B(x))

# Prints:
# 20 
# 9
```

However, I expected this to print `500` and `105` and not `20` and `9`. It appears that the import is "local" and does not affect `config.GLOBAL_VAL` and so the only way to accomplish what I want is by doing:

```
# main.py

from pkg import module_A, module_B
from pkg from config

config.GLOBAL_VAL = 100
x = 5
print(module_A.func_A(x))
print(module_B.func_B(x))

# Prints:
# 500 
# 105
```

My question is if there is some way to allow both `from pkg.config import GLOBAL_VAL` AND `from pkg from config` to work?

Comment: if you import the whole file, it should work, as in "import pkg.config" and then "GLOBAL_VAL = xx"

Comment: `GLOBAL_VAL` is just a name. When you assign to it you either create the name if it didn't already exist, or reassign the name to point to the new value. Why do you need a global? Just pass it as a parameter.

Answer (score 4):

### Explanation of What's Happening

`from pkg.config import GLOBAL_VAL`

This line assigns the name `GLOBAL_VAL` in the top-level scope to the value bound to the property `GLOBAL_VAL` of the module `pkg.config`. Any subsequent assignments to the name `GLOBAL_VAL` will actually only change the value that is bound to that name in the top-level scope (`pkg.config.GLOBAL_VAL` will remain unchanged).

Using `global` keyword actually will still not help you here, because `global` causes all references to the name in the global assignment to refer to the name bound in the top-level scope. Since we're already in the top-level scope, it effectively does nothing.

The only way to change the property called `GLOBAL_VAL` of `pkg.config` is to gain reference to the `pkg.config` object and then assign a new value to it's `GLOBAL_VAL` property.

### Answer

No, with `from pkg.config import GLOBAL_VAL`, it is not possible to mutate the value of `pkg.config.GLOBAL_VAL` by assigning a new value to the name `GLOBAL_VAL`. It's similar to how if I have a dictionary `d = {'a': 2}`, I can't change the value of `d['a']` by doing:

```py
v = d['a']
v = 3
print(d['a']) # still prints 2
```

Comment: Seems like you forgot the solution/answer?